# How to add a nice looking muzzle flash to the tip of my guns

Tags: 2d, graphics, libgdx

I am making a top down shooter and would like to add a muzzle flash to the tips of my guns. So I have an idea of what I want to do which would be just a circle that would fade from yellow to white or from white to yellow, don't really know yet. I actually have know clue how to fade in and fade out colors in libgdx so don't know how to do that. I guess I could also pass in a texture that I can color yellow and append that to the tip of the gun but still would like to add a color fade. Of course, these are just my crappy little ideas. Anyone else have a better idea that would look better graphically and if so could you try to describe it in some detail that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a discussion oriented poll. If you need to know how to fade textures, ask about that. But these type of "give me some ideas for X" are too open ended for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are many ways to do muzzle flashes for top-down games, and it's often subjective and depends on your situation. However, by far the most common approach I've seen is to simply use a texture that is shown for a very short time when the gun is fired.

As an example, I'll use [a game I made](http://congusbongus.itch.io/taiketsu) during [a recent game jam](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1573/26250), where I used the same approach.

Here's one of the textures (on black): [image] This is then shown for 100 milliseconds.

You can play the game online to see how it looks in action.

Muzzle flashes add a lot of polish for very little effort. Animation is often not required because it is such a brief effect.

Some other things you can consider (keep in mind these will fall under subjective territory):

- Adding a temporary light source at the muzzle
- Randomly selecting different muzzle textures to use every shot
- Very subtle animation
- Use different shapes and colors for the flashes to give guns a unique character
- The size of the flash subtly affects the player's perception of how powerful the gun is (similar to how the gun looks and sounds). It might look strange if a powerful gun has a subdued muzzle flash and vice versa.
- If you want, do a little research on muzzle flashes in real life, as this can help you make more interesting muzzle flashes. For example, many distinctive muzzle flashes are due to different flash suppressors.

Comment: Is it okay with you that I can use that muzzleflash image? That looks like a great flash.

Comment: @G3tinmybelly all the art from that game came from OpenGameArt.org; the muzzle flashes came from this pack: http://opengameart.org/content/space-ship-construction-kit